# Is there a way to override the CSS for the doc-sidebar (using Docusaurus) to make it narrower/further to the left?

Tags: css, docusaurus

I've been trying out Docusaurus for doing some documentation. Only problem is that I'd like more space for the page itself rather than the side bar/toc. I'm using preset-classic. I've tried overriding `--doc-sidebar-width` in custom.css but nothing changes. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right path, just add `!important`.

For others who may need this. In the file `.\src\css\custom.css`, add:

```
:root {
     --doc-sidebar-width: 220px !important;
}
```